# Numbers: divide in a column

Tags: numbers

I have a price list:

12,560
14,340
11,890
...

Is there a simple way to divide these cells by a number at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "spreadsheet" way to do this is to do the division in another column.

Lets say your data is column A, starts a row 1 and goes to row 10 (that's `A1:A10` in spreadsheet reference language).

In a unused column, row 1, you could enter:

```
=A1/10
```

And the copy and paste that formula from row 2 down to rows 2 through 10 in that column. Numbers will automatically increment the `A1` reference in the pasted cells.

The divisor (`10` in this case) can also be a reference if you like. Just make it a fixed reference so it doesn't automatically increment as you copy and paste. Lets say `B1` holds the value you want to divide everything in column `A` by. You'd use:

```
=A1/$B$1
```

as the formula and copy and paste. The `$` in front of the column name and row number tell Numbers not to auto-adjust those values as you paste the formula around to different cells.

[Here is an example Numbers '09 file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vnv8w51lncvt9w/Numbers-Example-001.numbers?dl=0).

Column A is data
Column B is A divided by 10
Column C is A divided by whatever value is in E2, change E2 and you'll see the values in Column C change.